# Proof of this property: $x=0$ if and only if $|x|<z$ for all $z>0$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, absolute-value, alternative-proof

I'm trying to prove a property that we've seen in our analysis lecture, but I have a little doubt about my way of doing it. The property is the following:

$$x=0 \Leftrightarrow |x| < z \text{ for all } z>0$$

...and we work with real numbers only.

I tried to prove it that way:

**1) First step: $x=0 \Rightarrow |x|<z \text{ for all } z>0$**

We know by a property of absolute values that $x=0 \Leftrightarrow |x|=0$, so $x=0$ means that $|x|=0$, which is smaller than $z$ for all $z>0$. Thus, $x=0 \Rightarrow |x|<z \text{ for all } z>0$.

**2) Second step: $|x|<z \text{ for all }z>0 \Rightarrow x=0$**

Let's suppose, on the contrary, that $|x|<z \text{ for all }z>0 \Rightarrow x \ne 0$, i.e. $x<0$ or $x>0$.

If $x<0$, then $|x|=-x < z$. This must be true for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$, but if $x=-2$, for example, then there exists $z$ (for example: $z=1$) such that the inequality above doesn't hold (we would have 2 < 1). So it's a contradiction.

If $x>0$, then $|x|=x < z$. Again, if $x=2$ and $z=1$, we have a contradiction.

As $x$ cannot be smaller or higher than $0$ without leading to a contradiction, the only possibility is that $x=0$.

I'm not sure about the second part of my proof, as it doesn't look as formal as usual... we usually only use axioms and properties derived from those axioms, so I'm not very happy with using counterexamples here. Does anyone know if there is another and nicer way to prove it?

Comment: Your second part is indeed very unformal, as using examples gives no proof! But you can look for a general rule that arises from your examples. You took $x=2$ and choose $z=1$ as a counter example. If you choose $x=4$ you could choose $z=2$... and so on! What number $z$ can you construct from $x$ which is smaller than $x\not=0$?

Comment: As I wanted to show that x<0 or x>0 were not true, I thought examples would be enough (if someone would tell me that "all flowers are red", I would show that it's wrong by finding a counterexample, i.e. a flower which is not red)... but apparently there is still something I'm missing about that. :(

And I realize that I wrote "for all z" almost everywhere instead of "for all z > 0". Sorry for that ; I'm going to edit it.

Finally... I don't really understand what you're suggesting ; something like z=x-1? But how does it help? Doesn't just that lead to more counterexamples? I'm lost.

Comment: It starts with your negation. The negation of $A\Rightarrow B$ is _not_ $A\Rightarrow \neg B$. This is the reason why counter examples are not enough. $z=x-1$ would not be a good idea, as it does not work for $z\leq 1$.

Comment: I can't believe I've not been able to write the negation properly. Thanks for making me noticing that. But now @AndreLu 's answer is disturbing, because my "fake negation" seems to be a way to prove it anyway... I'm so lost in all that "logical" stuff.

After reading Dean Young's answer, I guess you wanted me to find $z=|x|$...? The thing is, I've had such difficulty to find the correct negation already that it would have been probably impossible for me to find this by myself. And I didn't even thought about the fact that $|x| \le |x|$... I feel so stupid. But thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is flawed because you cannot prove a general fact from listing examples. Also the negation of "$|x| < y$ for all positive $y$" is "there exists some positive $y$ such that $|x| \geq y$", whereas you have its negation written as "$|x| < z$ for all $z \implies x \neq 0$, i.e. $x < 0$ or $x > 0$". Here is is how you could go about doing this:

Suppose first that $x = 0$. Then $|x| = 0$, which is smaller than any positive real number.

You attempted to prove the next part by contradiction, which could actually work, but the cleanest way is by contrapositive. Here is how that might work:

Suppose that $x \neq 0$. Then $|x| \neq 0$ and $|x| \geq 0$, so $|x| > 0$. In particular there is a positive number which is less than or equal to $|x|$, $|x|$ itself.

By contrapositive, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $|x| < y$ for every positive $y \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That is, indeed, a very clean way of doing it. And I would never have thought of using the fact that $|x| \le |x|$. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, we have $|x| < z$ for all $z>0$ and suppose for the sake of contradiction that $|x| \neq 0$. Since $|x| \geq 0$, this means, in this case, $|x| > 0$. But then, $|x| + |x| > |x|$. That is, $|x| > \frac{|x|}{2} >0 $, contradicting that $|x| < z$ for all $z > 0$. Therefore, our assumption that $|x| \neq 0$ isn't possible and it must be that $|x| = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a nice way to prove it too. I like it especially because it uses some axioms we've seen during our lecture, so thank you again :)